# Java Gui cannot scroll through scrollPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am creating a Gui in java and I wanted to have a list of selectable checkboxes in a smaller pane that allows you to scroll through it. I have it set  up but I may have messed up somewhere that it does not allow me to scroll, any help is appreciated.
GUI:

[image]

Code:

```
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(801, 500);

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    panel_1.setBorder(null);
    panel_1.setBackground(new Color(66, 69, 65));
    panel_1.setBounds(0, 0, 194, 483);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel_1);

    String[] sports = { "Select a sport", "NBA", "NFL", "NHL", "ATL", "MLB", "NCAA", "PGA", "CKE" }; // list of

    panel_1.setLayout(null);
    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Submit");
    btnNewButton.setBounds(52, 382, 89, 25);
    panel_1.add(btnNewButton);
    btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Leelawadee UI Semilight", Font.BOLD, 12));
    // items
    // contained
    // in drop
    // down
    JComboBox comboBox_1 = new JComboBox(sports);
    comboBox_1.setBounds(17, 345, 155, 22);
    panel_1.add(comboBox_1);
    comboBox_1.setMaximumRowCount(10);
    comboBox_1.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    comboBox_1.addActionListener(comboBox_1);
    comboBox_1.addActionListener(comboBox_1);
    comboBox_1.addActionListener(comboBox_1);

    JLabel lblSport = new JLabel("Sport\r\n");
    lblSport.setBounds(0, 321, 188, 18);
    lblSport.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    panel_1.add(lblSport);
    lblSport.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblSport.setFont(new Font("Leelawadee UI Semilight", Font.BOLD, 14));
    lblSport.setBackground(SystemColor.activeCaption);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    scrollPane.setBounds(0, 0, 188, 291);
    panel_1.add(scrollPane);

    JPanel panel_2_1 = new JPanel();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(panel_2_1);
    panel_2_1.setToolTipText(
            "This is where you input the URL of a gambling site that will be used in the calculator.");
    panel_2_1.setBorder(null);
    panel_2_1.setBackground(new Color(66, 69, 65));
    panel_2_1.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Sportsbook Selection");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
    lblNewLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    panel_2_1.add(lblNewLabel);
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    lblNewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblNewLabel.setLabelFor(frame);
    lblNewLabel.setBackground(SystemColor.activeCaption);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox = new JCheckBox("888Bets");
    chckbxNewCheckBox.setBounds(6, 43, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_2 = new JCheckBox("Bovada");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_2.setBounds(97, 43, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_2.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_2);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_1 = new JCheckBox("BlueBet");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_1.setBounds(6, 69, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_1.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_1);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_3 = new JCheckBox("Coral");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_3.setBounds(97, 69, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_3.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_3);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_4 = new JCheckBox("BoyleSports");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_4.setBounds(6, 95, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_4.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_4);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_5 = new JCheckBox("Circa Sports");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_5.setBounds(97, 95, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_5.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_5);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_6 = new JCheckBox("Betclic");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_6.setBounds(6, 121, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_6.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_6);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_2_1 = new JCheckBox("Casumo");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_2_1.setBounds(97, 121, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_2_1.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_2_1);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_1_1 = new JCheckBox("Betfair");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_1_1.setBounds(6, 147, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_1_1.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_1_1);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_3_1 = new JCheckBox("DraftKings");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_3_1.setBounds(97, 147, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_3_1.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_3_1);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_4_1 = new JCheckBox("BetMGM");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_4_1.setBounds(6, 173, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_4_1.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_4_1);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_5_1 = new JCheckBox("FanDuel");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_5_1.setBounds(97, 173, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_5_1.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_5_1);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_7 = new JCheckBox("BetOnline");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_7.setBounds(6, 199, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_7.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_7);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_2_2 = new JCheckBox("FOX Bet");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_2_2.setBounds(97, 199, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_2_2.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_2_2);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_1_2 = new JCheckBox("BetRivers");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_1_2.setBounds(6, 225, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_1_2.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_1_2);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_3_2 = new JCheckBox("GTbets");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_3_2.setBounds(97, 225, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_3_2.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_3_2);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_4_2 = new JCheckBox("Bet Victor");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_4_2.setBounds(6, 251, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_4_2.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_4_2);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_5_2 = new JCheckBox("Intertops");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_5_2.setBounds(97, 251, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_5_2.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_5_2);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_6_1 = new JCheckBox("BetUS");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_6_1.setBounds(6, 277, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_6_1.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_6_1);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_2_1_1 = new JCheckBox("Ladbrokes");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_2_1_1.setBounds(97, 277, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_2_1_1.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_2_1_1);

    JCheckBox chckbxLeovegas = new JCheckBox("LeoVegas");
    chckbxLeovegas.setBounds(6, 304, 89, 23);
    chckbxLeovegas.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxLeovegas);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_2_3 = new JCheckBox("LiveScore");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_2_3.setBounds(97, 304, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_2_3.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_2_3);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_1_3 = new JCheckBox("LowVig");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_1_3.setBounds(6, 330, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_1_3.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_1_3);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_3_3 = new JCheckBox("Matchbook");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_3_3.setBounds(97, 330, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_3_3.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_3_3);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_4_3 = new JCheckBox("MarathonkBet ");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_4_3.setBounds(6, 356, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_4_3.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_4_3);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_5_3 = new JCheckBox("Mr Green");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_5_3.setBounds(97, 356, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_5_3.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_5_3);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_6_2 = new JCheckBox("MyBookie");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_6_2.setBounds(6, 382, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_6_2.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_6_2);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_2_1_2 = new JCheckBox("Neds");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_2_1_2.setBounds(97, 382, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_2_1_2.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_2_1_2);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_1_1_1 = new JCheckBox("NordicBet");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_1_1_1.setBounds(6, 408, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_1_1_1.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_1_1_1);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_3_1_1 = new JCheckBox("PaddyPower");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_3_1_1.setBounds(97, 408, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_3_1_1.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_3_1_1);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_4_1_1 = new JCheckBox("PointsBet(AU)");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_4_1_1.setBounds(6, 434, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_4_1_1.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_4_1_1);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_5_1_1 = new JCheckBox("PointsBet(US)");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_5_1_1.setBounds(97, 434, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_5_1_1.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_5_1_1);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_7_1 = new JCheckBox("Pinnacle");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_7_1.setBounds(6, 460, 89, 23);
    chckbxNewCheckBox_7_1.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panel_2_1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_7_1);
```

I was hoping to make the checkboxes able to be scrolled through.`

Comment: Don't use a null layout. Don't use setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Scrolling will only work correctly when you use layout managers. You should be able to use a `GridLayout`. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples. Also, don't keep creating new Font objects. The font can be shared by all components.

Comment: You probably want radio buttons rather than checkboxes.  How are you going to display more than one website?  Your GUi would be easier to use if the betting sites were in a JComboBox and the sports were radio buttons or checkboxes.  Generally, radio buttons and checkboxes are used when the selection is limited (<= 5).

Answer (score 0):

See the below runnable code to see one way this can be done using a **JDialog** for a window and Layout managers. Be sure to read the comments in code. You should be able to adapt the concept to your specific application:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class SportBookingsDemo {

    //Class member variables:
    private JDialog dia;            // JDialog object (class global):
    private JCheckBox[] chks;       // JCheckBox object Array (class global):
    private JComboBox sportCombo;   // JDialog object (class global):
    private JButton submit;         // JButton object (class global):

    // Captions for All JCheckBoxes (class global):
    String[] sportsBookNames = {"888Bets", "Bovada", "BlueBet", "Coral", "BoyleSports",
        "Circa Sports", "Betclic", "Casumo", "Betfair", "DraftKings",
        "BetMGM", "FanDuel", "BetOnline", "FOX Bet", "BetRivers",
        "GTbets", "Bet Victor", "Intertops", "BetUS", "Ladbrokes",
        "LeoVegas", "LiveScore", "LowVig", "Matchbook", "MarathonkBet",
        "Mr Green", "MyBookie", "Neds", "NordicBet", "PaddyPower",
        "PointsBet(AU)", "PointsBet(US)", "Pinnacle"};
    
    // ArrayList of String to hold captions for selected checkboxes (class global):
    private ArrayList<String> bookings = new ArrayList<>();
   
    // String Variable to hold the selected Sport (class global):
    private String sport;

    // Constructor:
    public SportBookingsDemo() {
        // Create the Dialog Window:
        createDialog();

        // `Submit` button ActionPerformed event:
        submit.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            bookings.clear();
            sport = "";

            if (sportCombo.getSelectedItem().equals("Select a sport")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dia, "You must select a specific Sport!",
                        "No Sport Selected", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                sportCombo.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
            else {
                sport = sportCombo.getSelectedItem().toString();
            }
            System.out.println("Selected Bookings:");
            for (int i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
                if (chks[i].isSelected()) {
                    bookings.add(sportsBookNames[i]);
                }
            }
            if (bookings.isEmpty()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dia, "You must select at least one Sportsbook!",
                        "No Sportbook Selected", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                sportCombo.requestFocus();
                return;
            }

            // Display dialog results:
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
            sb.append("<html><center>Selected bookings for the Sport of:<br><br>");
            sb.append("<font size='5', color=blue><b>").append(sport).append("</b></font><br><br></center>");
            for (String bks : bookings) {
                sb.append("<font size='4', color=green>✓ </font>").append(bks).append("<br>");
            }
            sb.append("<br></html>");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dia, sb.toString(), "Bookings",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        });
    }

    // Application entry point...
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // App started this way to avoid the need for statics:
        new SportBookingsDemo().startApp(args);
    }

    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        // Display dialog window:
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            dia.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    // Method to create Dialog:
    private void createDialog() {
        dia = new JDialog();                    // Initialize JDialog.
        dia.setModal(true);                     // Set dialog to Modal.
        dia.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); //Dispose dialog when closed.
        dia.setTitle("Sports Book Dialog");     // Set dialog title caption.
        dia.setAlwaysOnTop(true);               // Dialog will always be on top of other windows.
        dia.setSize(280, 390);                  // Set dialog size.
        dia.setResizable(false);                // Make dialog non-sizeable.
        dia.setLocationRelativeTo(null);        // Open dialog window to center screen.
        
        // Decalre and initialize the JDialog's main content panel
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        // Set Horizontal and Vertical Gaps for mainPanel's default FlowLayout.
        FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout(); 
        /* Set Horiz and Vert layout Gaps. The helps ensure the 
           components in dialog are center aligned as a single 
           column.                 */
        layout.setHgap(140); layout.setVgap(10); 
        mainPanel.setLayout(layout); // Apply Layout.
        dia.add(mainPanel);          // Add mainPanel to dialog Window

        /* Declare and initialize a JLabel to display 
           the CheckBoxes scrollable list display. */
        JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("Sportsbook Selection");
        // Set the Font, font style, and font size for the title:
        label_1.setFont(new Font("Leelawadee UI Semilight", Font.BOLD, 14));
        // Set JLabel text Horizontal Alignment to center.
        label_1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER); 
        mainPanel.add(label_1); // Add title to mainPanel.

        /* Declare a JPanel to hold all the checkboxes that
           will be added to a JScrollPane within the dialog.
           We also ensure a GridLayout of -1 rows (as many 
           as needed) and 2 columns for the JPanel.     */
        JPanel chkPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(-1, 2));

        /* Initialize the chks[] JCheckBox Array to the required 
           length. This length is actually determined by the number
           of elements within the sportsBookNames[] array which
           will hereby be considered a `parallel` array to the chks[]
           array. Every CheckBox element contained within the chks[] 
           array will contain a Caption text from the sportsBookNames[]
           array at the same index value.         */
        chks = new JCheckBox[sportsBookNames.length];
        
        /* Iterate through the chks[] array elements and apply 
           JCheckBox objects to them with text captions derived 
           from the sportsBookNames[] array at the current 
           iterated index. Add each chks[] element (JCheckBox)
           to the `chkPanel` JPanel.        */ 
        for (int i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
            chks[i] = new JCheckBox(sportsBookNames[i]);
            chks[i].setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 12));
            chkPanel.add(chks[i]);
        }
        // Add the now filled chkPanel to a JScrollPane (`chkScroll`).
        JScrollPane chkScroll = new JScrollPane(chkPanel);
        // Set the ScrollPane's Preferred Size we want within te dialog.
        chkScroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 200));
        // Add the ScrollPane (`chkScroll`) to the Main Panel (`mainPanel`).
        mainPanel.add(chkScroll);

        /* Declare a JLabel to be a title for a Sport type JComboBox
           and provide a title:        */
        JLabel sportLBL = new JLabel("Sport");
        // Set the Font, font style, and font size for the title:
        sportLBL.setFont(new Font("Leelawadee UI Semilight", Font.BOLD, 14));
        // Add the JLabel (`sportLBL`) to the Main Panel (`mainPanel`).
        mainPanel.add(sportLBL);

        /* Create a JComboBox (`sportCombo`) and fill it with 
           Sport Types. Sport Type names are contained within
           the `sports[]` array.        */
        String[] sports = {"Select A Sport", "NBA", "NFL", "NHL",
            "ATL", "MLB", "NCAA", "PGA", "CKE"};
        sportCombo = new JComboBox<>(sports);
        sportCombo.setFont(new Font("Leelawadee UI Semilight", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        // Set the Preferred Size of the JComboBox (`sportCombo`):
        sportCombo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 25));
        // Make sure the ComboBox is non-editable.
        sportCombo.setEditable(false); 
        // Add the JComboBox (`sportCombo`) to the Main Panel (`mainPanel`).       
        mainPanel.add(sportCombo);

        /* Initialize the `submit` JButton and apply the 
           text caption of "Submit".            */
        submit = new JButton("Submit");
        submit.setFont(new Font("Leelawadee UI Semilight", Font.BOLD, 12));
        // Add the JButton (`submit`) to the Main Panel (`mainPanel`). 
        mainPanel.add(submit);
    }
}
```